# different results between matlab provided and self-defined neural network with the same parameters?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I have trained a neural network through matlab neural network toolbox.

After I saved the weights and bias of the trained neural network, I computed the results of neural network through some self-defined code like 'out= poslin(W1*input+b1)'.

Then I computed the results from the command provided by neural network toolbox, like 'out = net(input)' .

But the results are different when the weights, bias, transfer function are all the same. The output of matlab is '0.0221260335094049 -0.600000000000000'; the output of my network is '0.998704466284076 -1'.

The m file is :

```
load net_save;

view(net_save);

input =  [-0.6000;0;0;0;0;0];

%% the result of matlab defined neural network

out_matlab = net_save(input);

% save the weights and bias of the loaded network
b1 = net_save.b{1};
b2 = net_save.b{2};
b3 = net_save.b{3};

w1 = net_save.iw{1};
w2 = net_save.lw{2,1};
w3 = net_save.lw{3,2};


%% the result of own defined neural network

in = input;
in_layer1 = poslin(w1*in + b1);
in_layer2 = poslin(w2*in_layer1+b2);
out = tansig(w3*in_layer2+b3);
```

The structure of neural network is : 
[two hidden layers with 400 and 300 nodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ3gz.png)

The trained network can be find here: 
[train network](https://www.dropbox.com/s/en8upwtf9vd8ori/net_save.mat?dl=0)

besides, when training the network, I used 'poslin' transfer function for two hidden layers and 'tansig' transfer function for output layer.

The command is :

```
net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'poslin';
net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'poslin';
net.layers{3}.transferFcn = 'tansig';
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Has matlab neural toolbox network poslin activation function in hidden units and tangsin on output?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Yes, I used the poslin transfer function for two hidden layers and tansig transfer function for output layer. The command is ' net.layers{1}.transferFcn = 'poslin';
     net.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'poslin';
     net.layers{3}.transferFcn = 'tansig';'

Comment: From mathematical point, is impossible have different results with same parameters. I agree with your part of code, maybe is problem with result extraction from neural toolbox?

Comment: sorry, what's the meaning 'result extraction from neural toolbox'? Do you mean the method to define b1,b2,b3,w1,w2,w3? :)

Comment: Yes, they technically seems fine, but isn't possible you extract a bad set of weights or biases? Also information about output from NN toolbox net and yours will be helpfull :)

Comment: The NN toolbox has built-in normalization. Most likely your inputs and outputs will be linearly transformed.

Comment: @Diphtong I think it's a good point. But here I want to used the nn network weights in another environment. So how can I know the process of NN toolbox? Could you please explain more?

Comment: @viceriel I think I used the right command to extract the weights. It's a good point to add my outputs. I have re-edited the question.

Comment: @viceriel problem solved ! Because when create the network object, matlab will create input and output processing automatically. More info can be found : https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/choose-neural-network-input-output-processing-functions.html.  Thank you !

Comment: @Diphtong problem solved!  Thank you very much ~